# Como puedo abrir un modal/popup automaticamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modal

quiero hacer que cuando se mande un registro aparezca un modal automáticamente sin necesidad de darle de ningún boton y que luego redireccione la web a otra página. He probado con un jquery, pero la verdad es que no lo manejo muy bien y no se como hacerlo. De momento no tengo puesto aun el form, quiero hacer que funcione antes el modal si es posible:

```
!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
    });
    </script>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado por favor

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con esta función:

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
         setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://ejemplo.com', '_blank');}, 2000);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Pero el modal no debe aparecer en automático sino hasta que se mande un registro

Comment: Si entiendo, pero dijiste que primero querías probar que funcionará antes de poner un form

Comment: Yo no soy el autor de la pregunta, solo te hago la observación, por otro lado ¿si ya tiene JQuery por que usas `window.onload` no sería mejor seguir por el código ya propuesto y usar el `document.ready` de JQuery?

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo edite

Comment: basicamente lo que quiero hacer es con php devolver una variable booleana y si es true que entre en el script y muestre el modal conforme se ha registrado y al darle al boton cerrar del modal o dar click fuera del modal redireccione a la pagina de login.